# SSH - SSH into a host, under a router which you don't have access (can't forward the port)

Tags: networking, ssh

Host A wants to ssh into Host B which is behind a router. We don't have access to the router of Host B, so we can't do port forwading.

Which other alternatives are there for allowing Host A to ssh into Host B?

Comment: Quick comment, there is something called reverse SSH, maybe this could be of help to you? Reverse SSH means you ssh from host B to host A and reverse the connection, you can SSH this way

Comment: @MaartenOlijve Can you please give an example with working commands?

Answer (score 1):

One alternative that I've used for this purpose is to set up a VPN with an access point somewhere reachable by both Host A and Host B, i.e. somewhere on the internet. I suggest looking into [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) and its examples. This way you can virtualize a network through which you can access any other hosts connected as if they were on the same network.

OpenVPN is pretty powerful, so providing a step-by-step guide would be beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: This is also known as a "jump server" - and the only way to get around the lack of port forwarding, as far as I am aware, +1

Answer (score 0):

There is one more alternative. Give host B regular IP address. Not NATTing, no RFC1918 IPs. Just a normal IP. Then (firewall rules allowing) everyone can ssh directly to host B.

Comment: Can you explain how?

Comment: Log in on host A (e.g. your own desktop) and type `ssh hostB.domainfromB.tld`.  That should just work.
It only gets harder if firm B adds firewalls, or does not give B a direclty reachable IP. Then you need to work around these barriers. (And for hosts B which are at home there often is such a barrier in the form or NAT, caused by us running out of IP v4 addresses and ugly workarounds. This is temporarily though. IPv6 and a much bigger IP pool has been introduced a few decades ago and is slowly getting implemented).

Comment: So you mean `ssh public_ip.private_ip` ? Do I need to tell, Host B is also a personal computer under a router, there is no firm.