# SSH gateway server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

Is there anyway to set up a ssh gateway server? What I am trying to setup is a way to connect to a specific linux shell on a Lan remotely from the internet without using port numbers. So for example login on would look like this

```
ssh server1.domain.com
```

or

```
ssh server2.domain.com
```

instead of
`ssh domain.com:(portnumber)` and having port forwarding map `(portnumber)` to port 22 of the servers private IP address

Each server would have a private IP address and share the public IP.

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH - SSH into a host, under a router which you don't have access (can't forward the port)](http://superuser.com/questions/1050318/ssh-ssh-into-a-host-under-a-router-which-you-dont-have-access-cant-forward)

Comment: @Lightning77  It can be achieved by an open-source tool called Ezeelogin -  https://www.ezeelogin.com

Comment: In case someone arrives at this (more esoteric) question, while looking for the more common scenario described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190490/how-to-use-ssh-over-http-or-https

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible in your described way, because `ssh` does not use any concept of domains and sub-domains (hostname is not part of protocol, as it is for HTTP). It is using hostnames only to get IP address and it is used (and port of course). Your concept would only work if you would have list of public IP addresses, which you probably don't have when you ask this question.

This case is commonly solved using `jumpbox` server, where you connect using public IP and from there you see local network (with possibly local DNS names). This requires to use, for example:

```
ssh -t jumpbox ssh anotherhost.localdomain
```

but it can be simplified using `ProxyCommand` in client configuration:

```
Host *.localdomain
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p jumpbox
```

And then the connection to distant node is transparent. When you type

```
ssh anotherhost.localdomain
```

it will bring you to the target host over the `jumpbox`.

Comment: The ProxyCommand method is best, because it doesn't expose the plaintext to the jumpbox itself (as the `ssh -t` method would).

Comment: @grawity Thanks. That is good point. But the middle way is easier to understand for users.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the command to setup an SSH gateway server:

```
$ ssh -L 2222:secureserver:22 user@gateway cat -
```

Enter the password when prompted (but you should really be using public key authentication, anyway). After this, in another terminal, use this to connect to the secure server.

```
$ ssh -p 2222 user2@localhost
```

That’s it. You can now use ssh, scp, or any other command to directly talk to the secure server through the gateway. You only need to run the first command once and keep it running in a hidden terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `-J` / `ProxyJump`:

> ```
> -J destination
>        Connect to the target host by first making a ssh connection to the
>        jump host described by destination and then establishing a TCP
>        forwarding to the ultimate destination from there.  Multiple jump
>        hops may be specified separated by comma characters.  This is a
>        shortcut to specify a ProxyJump configuration directive.  Note that
>        configuration directives supplied on the command-line generally
>        apply to the destination host and not any specified jump hosts.  Use
>        ~/.ssh/config to specify configuration for jump hosts.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread, but my 2 cents:

> "Teleport SSH Gateway" is a good open source option

https://goteleport.com/blog/ssh-jump-server/